# how to remove data before a character in java

Tags: android

In my application, I am appending string to create path to generate URL. Now I want to remove that appended string on pressing back button.
Suppose this is the string :

```
String1/String2/String3/String4/String5
```

Now I want a string like this:

```
String2/String3/String4/String5
```

How can I do this??

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String a = "String1/String2/String3/String4/String5";
a = a.substring(a.indexOf("/") + 1, a.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do this

```
String appendedString = "String1/String2/String3/String4/String5";

appendedString = appendedString.substring(appendedString.indexOf("/") + 1);
```

you will get the remaining `String` after the first `/`

Answer (score 0):

[Java Regular expression](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

Write regular expression for same and replace the matching string.

Answer (score 0):

hi do something like this

```
String CurrentString = "String1/String2/String3/String4/String5";

    String[] separated = CurrentString.split("/");
    String newData = "";
    String delimiter = "/";
    for (int i = 1; i < separated.length; i++) {
        if (i == separated.length - 1) {
            delimiter = "";
        }
        newData = newData + separated[i] + delimiter;
    }
    System.out.println("newData= " + newData);
```

finally the newData will be given as

```
newData= String2/String3/String4/String5
```

another simple way is

```
  String givenString = "String1/String2/String3/String4/String5";

    givenString = givenString.substring(givenString.indexOf("/") + 1);

    System.out.println("givenString= " + givenString);
```

which will give you the output

```
givenString= String2/String3/String4/String5
```